# Using iMovie, is there a way to "blur out" a section of video

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, imovie

I want to edit a movie file, but blur out or cover up a certain spot on the screen for a few seconds.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What version of iMovie?